# Landing page not displayed in browser

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

Everytime I run `ipthon notebook` in terminal, a blank page pops up in Chrome, instead of a normal dashboard page.

**Relevant info**

System: Mac OS X Yosemite
ipython in terminal works fine
All python staff is installed by Anaconda package

```
$ python -c "import IPython; print(IPython.sys_info())"
{'commit_hash': '1c0eb68',
 'commit_source': 'installation',
 'default_encoding': 'UTF-8',
 'ipython_path': '/Users/philip/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython',
 'ipython_version': '2.3.1',
 'os_name': 'posix',
 'platform': 'Darwin-14.1.0-x86_64-i386-64bit',
 'sys_executable': '/Users/philip/anaconda/bin/python',
 'sys_platform': 'darwin',
 'sys_version': '2.7.9 |Anaconda 2.1.0 (x86_64)| (default, Dec 15 2014, 10:37:34) \n[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5577)]'}
```

**Start server with debug flag in terminal**

```
$ ipython notebook --debug
2015-02-08 11:37:37.661 [NotebookApp] Config changed:
2015-02-08 11:37:37.661 [NotebookApp] {'Application': {'log_level': 10}}
2015-02-08 11:37:37.661 [NotebookApp] IPYTHONDIR set to: /Users/philip/.ipython
2015-02-08 11:37:37.662 [NotebookApp] Using existing profile dir: u'/Users/philip/.ipython/profile_default'
2015-02-08 11:37:37.662 [NotebookApp] Searching path [u'/Users/philip/Downloads/quant/backtesting', u'/Users/philip/.ipython/profile_default'] for config files
2015-02-08 11:37:37.662 [NotebookApp] Attempting to load config file: ipython_config.py
2015-02-08 11:37:37.664 [NotebookApp] Loaded config file: /Users/philip/.ipython/profile_default/ipython_config.py
2015-02-08 11:37:37.664 [NotebookApp] Attempting to load config file: ipython_notebook_config.py
2015-02-08 11:37:37.665 [NotebookApp] Loaded config file: /Users/philip/.ipython/profile_default/ipython_notebook_config.py
2015-02-08 11:37:37.668 [NotebookApp] Adding cluster profile 'default'
2015-02-08 11:37:37.668 [NotebookApp] searching for local mathjax in [u'/Users/philip/.ipython/nbextensions']
2015-02-08 11:37:37.668 [NotebookApp] Serving local MathJax from /Users/philip/.ipython/nbextensions/mathjax/MathJax.js at /nbextensions/mathjax/MathJax.js
2015-02-08 11:37:37.742 [NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /Users/philip/Downloads/quant/backtesting
2015-02-08 11:37:37.742 [NotebookApp] 0 active kernels
2015-02-08 11:37:37.742 [NotebookApp] The IPython Notebook is running at: http://localhost:8888/
2015-02-08 11:37:37.742 [NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
```

**Remedies I have tried so far**

Remove entire anaconda package. Use brew version of python interpreter instead. `pip install ipython[all]`. After that, I still get a blank page.

It makes me wonder it has something to do with OS X system, not really an python/ipython/notebook/anaconda issue. Maybe some system libraies are missing or not symlinked etc. The quesion is how to debug that?

#### Update

After update ipython via conda, I still got blank landing page

Answer (score 0):

I fix the problem after 10+ hours of iterative debug. In the end of day, it's simply a missing line "127.0.0.1 localhost" in hosts file. As a result, Chrome cannot resolve localhost. I have no idea how that line is removed or when. But thank god, it's over.